# stop Activity from displaying - Push notification (Parse)

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have just implemented Parse push notifications into my app. I want to be able to show the push notification, but i don't want the app to open when the user presses the Push notification. Instead, i just want the notification to be dismissed.

i would imagine it would be handled by the ParsePushBroadcastReciever, but i can't find anything online which fits my purpose.

Here is my subclassed ParsepushBroadcastReciever:

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("Push", "Clicked");
            Intent i = new Intent(context, HomeScreen.class);
            i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for you to programatically dismiss a notification you will need to call [cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)) using a [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) instance passing in the ID that was passed into [notify()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)) on the NotificationManager (since this is what actually pushes the notification into the notification pane).  You can't do this using the Parse SDK alone since you will need to take control of the population of notifications yourself.

First you will need to setup a `NotificationManager` instance then when a notification is ready to be pushed you assign it a value that you can reference later when cancelling like this:

```
public class MyParsePushBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

  NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
  int notification_id = 0;

   @Override
   public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.e("Push", "Clicked");
     mNotificationManager.cancel(notification_id)             
     }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        ...
   }

   @Override
    protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Notification n = super.getNotification(context, intent);
        notification_id = intent.getExtras().getInt("NOTIFICATION_TYPE");
        mNotificationManager.notify(notification_id, n);
        return null;
    }
}
```

So you see by taking control of the `NotificationManager` (instead of passing it off to the Parse SDK to assign some unknown value) we can know exactly which values to use when calling cancel.  I am letting the system build my `Notification` object (and I get it using `super.getNotification()`) but you are free to also use a [Notification builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) to create the notification yourself as well.